# Django Serializer with multiple database

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-serializer

I have a Django application. I have two databases in the backend, One is PostgreSQL and one is Redshift. I am using serializer concept in DB operation. I need to process each DB in different scenarios. But when I check the insertion in Django, getting below error,

```
'{'care_gap_fact_id': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}'
```

But this field is a primary key and auto increment.

below are the other details,

```
data = {
        #"care_gap_fact_id": 7,
        "start_date_id": 10,
    }
    seriali = CaregapfactSerializer(data=data)
    if seriali.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        try :
            instance = seriali.save(using='postgres')
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```

'postgres' is one of my databases.

I tried the below method as well,

```
database_name = 'your_database_name'
database_connection = connections[database_name]

# Create the serializer and save the object using the specific database connection
serializer = YourSerializer(data=request.data)

if serializer.is_valid():
    obj = serializer.save(using=database_connection)
    # Process further if needed
else:
    # Handle serializer validation errors
```

But this is also not working.

Below is my model class,

```
class CareGapFact(models.Model):
    care_gap_fact_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    start_date_id=models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Below is my serializer class,

```
class CaregapfactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CareGapFact
        fields = ["care_gap_fact_id","start_date_id"]
```

If I have removed "care_gap_fact_id" from serializer fields, I am getting the error below,

```
  Got a `TypeError` when calling `CareGapFact.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `CareGapFact.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the CaregapfactSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
    Original exception was:
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\python_projects\panelnew\panel\panel\newpanelenv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 962, in create
        instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "D:\python_projects\panelnew\panel\panel\newpanelenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "D:\python_projects\panelnew\panel\panel\newpanelenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 656, in create
        obj = self.model(**kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "D:\python_projects\panelnew\panel\panel\newpanelenv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 567, in __init__
        raise TypeError(
    TypeError: CareGapFact() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'using'
```

PLEASE HELP ME TO SOLVE THIS.

Comment: try replacing the `IntegerField` with `BigAutoField` in your id field and remove it from serializer